# click event is not working in innerhtml string angular 6

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular6

I am working on an generate dynamic template using angular 6. I have an API that return strings like below:

```html
    <button type="button" (click)="openAlert()">click me</button>
```

and html

```html
    <div [innerHtml]="myTemplate | safeHtml">
      </div>
```

function is bellow:

```js
    openAlert() {
        alert('hello');
      }
```

Comment: There should be some error in your browser console.

Comment: no error console is clear

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz example>

Comment: This will not work, because method contains in string will be treated as text

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot bind angular events directly to innerHTML.

Still if you need to attach the event listeners you need to to do it after the html content is loaded.

Once the content is set to the variable, ngAfterViewInit Angular life cycle event will be triggered. Here you need to attach the required event listeners.

Checkout the working example below.

component.html

```
<button (click)="addTemplate()">Get Template</button>
<div [innerHTML]="myTemplate | safeHtml"></div>
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  myTemplate  = '';

  constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef){

  }
  openAlert() {
    alert('hello');
  }
  addTemplate(){
     this.myTemplate  = '<button type="button" id="my-button" (click)="openAlert()">click mee</buttn>';
  }
  ngAfterViewChecked (){
    if(this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#my-button')){
      this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#my-button').addEventListener('click', this.openAlert.bind(this));
    }
  } 
}
```

safe-html.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
@Pipe({
  name: 'safeHtml'
})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(value) {
        return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
    }

}
```

Comment: Putting it in afterViewChecked will potentially add the same handler multiple times.

Comment: Edited the original answer to replace ngAfterViewChecked with ngAfterViewInit.

Comment: @Farzin Zaker ngAfterViewInit is invoked only once when the view is instantiated. But ngAfterViewChecked is called after the default change detector has completed checking a component's view for changes. This is useful when you set data after component is loaded. Example after api call response.

Answer (score 2):

this should work too:

component.html

```
<div #template></div>
```

component.ts

```
@ViewChild('template') myTemplate: ElementRef;

addTemplate(){
   this.myTemplate.nativeElement.innerHTML = '<button type="button">click me</button>';
   this.myTemplate.nativeElement.addEventListener('click', this.openAlert);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically this will not work. When you write code in Angular, it is `transpiled` by webpack and converted to javascript that is executed in the browser.

However, now you are injecting `Angular code` dynamically and not `build`ing it. The event detection `(click)` would not work natively and the function `openAlert` is also not in the global scope where it is injected. You will have to consider a different approach and generate content using `<ng-template>` based on response from the `API`.