# Element inside a modal not responding to click event in angular

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, click

I want to call a method when an element in a modal is clicked. I've done this before using js/jquery in a project I once worked on, but now I'm using angular to rewrite the project.

Here is a js/jquery script that works fine for me

```
<!Doctype html>
 <html lang ="en">
  <head>
   <meta charset ="utf-8" />
     <title>Popup Modal</title>
     <style>
       .wrap {
           position: absolute;
           top: 10%;
           right: 10%;
           bottom: 85px;
           left: 10%;
           padding: 20px 50px;
           display: block;
           transform: translateY(20px);
           transition: all 0.5s;
           visibility: hidden;
           background: green;
        }

        .wrap.active {
            display: block;
            visibility: visible;
            box-shadow: 2px 3px 16px silver;
            transition: all 600ms;
            transform: translateY(0px);
            transition: all 0.5s;
         }

         .wrap.active .content {
            position: relative;
            z-index: 1;
            opacity: 1;
            transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);
         }

      </style>

     <script src ="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
     <script>
        function showModal(selector){
          $('#modal_content').html($(selector).show());
          $('.wrap').show().toggleClass('active');
          return false;
      }

      function showAlert(msg){
         alert(msg);
      }

     $(function (){
        $('#say-hi').on('click', ()=>{
           showAlert('Hello guys');
       })
     })
  </script>
</head>
<body>
   <p id="paragraph" style="display: none;">
     This is a paragraph that I want to show inside modal<br /><br />
     <button id="say-hi">Click to get alert</button>
   </p>

   <div class='wrap screen_center' style="display: none;">
     <div id ="modal_content" class='content'>
       content
     </div>
   </div>
   <a onclick="showModal('#paragraph');">Click me</a>
 </body>
 </html>
```

The js/jquery above works fine. Below is the angular version

Here is the ts file

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
  @Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
  })

  export class AppComponent {
    @ViewChild('modal_wrapper') modalWrapper;
    @ViewChild('modal_content') modalContent;
    @ViewChild('paragraph') paragraph;

    showInModal: boolean = false;

    constructor(){}

    showModal(contentSelector){
      const modalEl = this.modalWrapper.nativeElement;
      const modalContentEl = this.modalContent.nativeElement;
      const paragraphEl = this.paragraph.nativeElement;

      modalContentEl.innerHTML = paragraphEl.outerHTML;

      console.log('modal wrapper: ', this.modalWrapper, 'modal content: ', this.modalContent, 'paragraph: ', this.paragraph);

      modalEl.classList.toggle('active');
   }

   showAlert(msg){
      alert(msg);
   }  

 }
```

Here is the .html file

```
<button (click)="showModal('#paragraph');" >Open Modal</button>
<div #paragraph>
   <p>
      This is a paragraph that I want to show inside modal<br /><br />
      <button (click)="showAlert('Hello guys');">Click to get alert</button>
   </p>
</div> 

  <div #modal_wrapper class='modal centered top' >
    <div #modal_content class="modal_content">
       content
    </div>
  </div>
```

And lastly here is the .css file

```
.modal {
   position: absolute;
   overflow: hidden;
   top: 70px;
   bottom: 85px;
   padding: 10px 25px;
   display: block;
   border-radius: 4px;
   transform: translateY(20px);
   transition: all 0.5s;
   visibility: hidden;
   background: ghostwhite;
   width: 95%;
   min-height: 70%;
 }
 .modal .modal_content {
   opacity: 0;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   max-height: 90%;
 }
 .modal.active {
   display: block;
   visibility: visible;
   box-shadow: 2px 3px 16px silver;
   transition: all 600ms;
   transform: translateY(0px);
   transition: all 0.5s;
 }

 .modal.active .modal_content {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 1;
   opacity: 1;
   transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);
 }

 .centered {
   position: fixed;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   margin-top: -150px;
   margin-left: -150px;
 }

 .top{
   z-index: 99 !important;
 }  
 .modal{
   width: 60%;
   margin-left: -30%;
 }
```

I'm pretty new to angular, I really don't know what I'm doing wrong. Anyone with Idea should help me out. Thanks in adv

I've created it on stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-feuvem
the "click to get alert" button is not firing the alert, that's the problem. I've edited the stackblitz url so that you can view the code

Comment: This won't help the issue, just for the sake of code quality. Don't query elements in Angular, use `@ViewChild`. Or to toggle a class do `[class.active]="modalActive"`

Comment: I wish I can do this,

Comment: @BojanKogoj I've edited the code to reflect your suggestion but the alert in the modal is still not popping up. I've also modified the stackblitz files

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you're attempting to just put HTML inside some HTML and hope that the scripting portion of it will just work (i.e. the inclusion of the click function).

At a glance, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58641615/click-event-is-not-working-in-innerhtml-string-angular-6) issue looks like it covers what you want to do.